# Command to wrap all anchor links between li tags with VIM?

Tags: html, vim

I have something like this:

```
<div class="portfolio" id="portfolio">
<ul id="tiles">
<a href="http://www.lisami520.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/311.jpg"><img
class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-278" alt="31"
src="http://www.lisami520.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/311-225x300.jpg" width="225" height="300" /></a> <a
href="http://www.lisami520.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/302.jpg"><img
class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-277" alt="30"
src="http://www.lisami520.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/302-225x300.jpg" width="225" height="300" /></a> <a
href="http://www.lisami520.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/292.jpg"><img
class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-276" alt="29"
src="http://www.lisami520.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/292-225x300.jpg" width="225" height="300" /></a>
```

I want to wrap all the anchor links with `<li></li>` tags with a single command.

How to accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the two commands?

```
:% s/<a/<li><a/g
:% s@</a>@</a></li>@g
```

- `:` => enter a command
- `%` => do this on all lines
- `s/xxx/yyy/g`  => substitute (s) xxx with yyy for all occurrences on a line (g)
- `s@xxx@yyy@g` => the same as before, but use @ as the delimiter, because / is part of xxx and/or yyy

Comment: +1 for the straightforward. could be merged into one: `%s/<a/<li>&/g|%s#/a>#&</li>#g`

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is using the `\_.` meta-character, which can match newlines.  This will fail if you have nested anchor tags, but of course that would be invalid HTML.  Of course, any method using regular expressions can be fooled by matches inside comments, scripts, strings, etc., so use some caution.

```
:%s@<a\>\_.\{-\}</a>@<li>&</li>@g
```

Note that I added an end-of-word item, `\>`, just in case someone invents a tag like `<apple></apple>` and you find it in your code.  Also, the non-greedy `.\{-\}` instead of `.*` is important here.

In addition to the references in @kkeller's answer, see

```
:help /\>
:help /\_.
:help /\{-
```